# Force to use HTTPS redirects page to http://http/ url

Tags: ssl, redirect, iis, web-config, orchardcms

I have added this code into my `Configuration -> system.webServer` section of  `web.config` file to force users to use https:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
            redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
            pattern=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

But when I go to my website, it redirects page to this url:
`http://http/`

Notes:

- I am using Orchard CMS version 1.10.x
- When I use Orchard's SSL plugin to force all pages to use SSL, this happens again.
- SSL Redirection is enabled in Orchard's settings.
- SSL/TLS Certificate is correctly set in my Plesk control panel.
- Website is currently secured using "Let's Encrypt". This issue happens when I use Cloudflare services too.
- This happens on every web browser I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same rewrite rules to redirect my pages to https using Orchard on a Plesk panel with Let's Encrypt certificates. This rule redirects every http call to https.
You have to disable the Orchard Secure Sockets Layer plugin since you make your own rules in web.config.
If you want to use the Orchard plugin, remove your rewrite rules and work with the plugin instead.

Comment: I tried both. First I disabled the SSL Plugin and used above snippet. Then Enabled SSL plugin and removed the snippet, but still the same problem in both cases.